# How to add a datetime record between rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table like below but thousands of rows, so the idea is 3rd and 4th April, 10th and 11th April are missing in proper date order that days are actually days off of an employee? If I do `pd.merge` with a big calendar that's not what I'm looking for, so how can I generate these missing dates between rows?

[image]

Expected data

[image]

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insert-row-at-given-position-in-pandas-dataframe/

Comment: `df.reindex(pd.date_range(start, end, freq='D'))`